# Change route (URL) for Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, flask, google-cloud-functions

I'm following the tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd#python-preview_3. This has the following lines:

```
@https_fn.on_request()
def addmessage(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
```

This results in a url like `.../project/us-central1/addmessage?text=message`.

Since this is Flask based, I was hoping to be able to set routes, like `@app.route("api/v1/<message>")`. Is this possible in firebase functions?

Comment: No, the only path you have is the name of the function. To use path-based routes consider Cloud Run which is the big brother to Cloud Functions.